# Azure Blob Container - Upload Blob with same Name property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am allowing users in my application to attach files to a valuation when it has been run. A problem I foresee is a user attaching/uploading the same document to different valuations. These files are stored in an Azure Blob Storage Container and have custom metadata properties.

Here's some code showing my API service:

```
foreach (var blob in blobs.Files)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        // Get a reference to the blob just uploaded from the API in a container from configuration settings
                        BlobClient client = container.GetBlobClient(blob.FileName);

                        // Open a stream for the file we want to upload
                        await using (Stream? data = blob.OpenReadStream())
                        {
                            // Upload the file async
                            await client.UploadAsync(data);
                        }

                        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

                        // Set metadata properties
                        var metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            {"Guid", guid.ToString()},
                            {"UserId", valuation.UserId.ToString()},
                            {"TenantId", valuation.TenantId.ToString()},
                            {"ValuationId", valuation.Id.ToString()}
                        };

                        // Update blob metadata
                        await client.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);

                        Document document = new Document()
                        {
                            Guid = guid.ToString(),
                            FileName = blob.FileName,
                            FileType = blob.ContentType,
                            FileUrl = client.Uri.AbsoluteUri,
                            ValuationId = valuation.Id,
                            UserId = valuation.UserId,
                            TenantId = valuation.TenantId
                        };

                        await _ctx.Document.AddAsync(document);
                        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

                        // Everything is OK and file got uploaded
                        blobResponse.Status = $"File {blob.FileName} Uploaded Successfully";
                        blobResponse.Error = false;
                        blobResponse.Blobs.Add(new BlobDTO
                        {
                            Name = client.Name,
                            Uri = client.Uri.AbsoluteUri
                        });
                    }
                    // If the file already exists, we catch the exception and do not upload it
                    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
                    when (ex.ErrorCode == BlobErrorCode.BlobAlreadyExists)
                    {
                        blobResponse.Status = $"File with name {blob.FileName} already exists. Please use another name to store your file.";
                        blobResponse.Error = true;
                        serviceResponse.Success = false;
                        serviceResponse.Message = "Filename already exists";
                        serviceResponse.Data = blobResponse;
                        return serviceResponse;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        blobResponse.Status = $"Unexpected error: {ex.StackTrace}. Check log with StackTrace ID.";
                        blobResponse.Error = true;
                        serviceResponse.Success = false;
                        serviceResponse.Message = "Unexpected error";
                        serviceResponse.Data = blobResponse;
                    }
                }
```

Is it possible to change the file name? If not, how can I handle this situation while retaining the file name for reference?

Comment: "_Is it possible to change the file name?_" - **no**: Blobs cannot be renamed. If your blobs are immutable then I recommend you use content-addressable-storage (i.e. name your blobs after their SHA-256 hash in Base16). You can store original filenames in blob-metadata if you like.

Comment: BTW, your `try/catch` is not transactional: there are numerous points within your `try{}` block where an exception will be thrown _after_ some data has been partially saved, but your code doesn't attempt to roll-back any of the changes made so-far. You should fix that.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)` <-- Don't do this: never catch `Exception`, only catch _specific_ exception types that are known to be thrown and even then, only when you know you can correctly handle them. The only exception (pun unintended) is if you use `throw;` (and not `throw ex;`) to re-throw a caught `Exception` after doing a rollback or log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is use `guid` for the blob name and then store the actual file name as metadata.

Your code would be something like:

```
foreach (var blob in blobs.Files)
{

    try
    {

        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        // Get a reference to the blob just uploaded from the API in a container from configuration settings
        BlobClient client = container.GetBlobClient(guid.ToString());

        // Open a stream for the file we want to upload
        await using (Stream? data = blob.OpenReadStream())
        {
            // Upload the file async
            await client.UploadAsync(data);
        }

        // Set metadata properties
        var metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Guid", guid.ToString()},
            {"UserId", valuation.UserId.ToString()},
            {"TenantId", valuation.TenantId.ToString()},
            {"ValuationId", valuation.Id.ToString()},
            {"FileName", blob.FileName}
        };

        // Update blob metadata
        await client.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);

        Document document = new Document()
        {
            Guid = guid.ToString(),
            FileName = blob.FileName,
            FileType = blob.ContentType,
            FileUrl = client.Uri.AbsoluteUri,
            ValuationId = valuation.Id,
            UserId = valuation.UserId,
            TenantId = valuation.TenantId
        };

        await _ctx.Document.AddAsync(document);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Everything is OK and file got uploaded
        blobResponse.Status = $"File {blob.FileName} Uploaded Successfully and saved as {guid.ToString()}";
        blobResponse.Error = false;
        blobResponse.Blobs.Add(new BlobDTO
        {
            Name = client.Name,
            Uri = client.Uri.AbsoluteUri
        });
    }
    // If the file already exists, we catch the exception and do not upload it
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    when (ex.ErrorCode == BlobErrorCode.BlobAlreadyExists)
    {
        blobResponse.Status = $"File with name {blob.FileName} already exists. Please use another name to store your file.";
        blobResponse.Error = true;
        serviceResponse.Success = false;
        serviceResponse.Message = "Filename already exists";
        serviceResponse.Data = blobResponse;
        return serviceResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        blobResponse.Status = $"Unexpected error: {ex.StackTrace}. Check log with StackTrace ID.";
        blobResponse.Error = true;
        serviceResponse.Success = false;
        serviceResponse.Message = "Unexpected error";
        serviceResponse.Data = blobResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this was the solution I arrived at, thanks!